# Free Alternatives for SQL Prompt

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any free/open source alternative of SQL Prompt? SSMS 2008 R2 intellisense is good but I need it for code optimization. For example it should notify me when there is an unused variable declared.

Comment: I'm not sure if this does what you want but Navicat works good for being free.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not free! http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlserver/sqlserver_overview.html

Comment: It's closed, but it still help me and my company. We're a small team and have been using Sql Prompt for years. When we upgraded to SQL 2012 our old sql prompt stopped working. We missed it dearly, but I wasn't prepared to pay the price. This thread helped us find the right solution. Cheers

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 12):

You can try out the free SSMS and VS add-in, [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

ApexSQL Complete provides snippets and syntax checking and a lot of code auto-complete features (context based predicting keywords, users, objects, autocompleting aliases, the Insert procedure parameters automatically option , the Insert full INSERT statement option and so on)

For code refactoring you could use [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx), also a free add-in

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: ApexSQL doesn't seem to support Linked Servers that well.  I have a linked server defined with different credentials stored and Apex would keep prompting for the credentials because it's using my current session credentials instead of the saved one defined in the linked server.  This becomes problematic in environments where you have access to the linked server, but don't have knowledge of what the actual credentials are.  SQL Prompt has no issues with figuring this out and automatically using the saved credentials for the linked server.

Comment: You are right ApexSQL doesn't support Linked Servers also it hangs my SSMS means it freezes my SSMS and takes time more than a min to load. But I love Refactor and Apex Search

Comment: ApexSQL has poor performance, its not good option.

Comment: Not as good as SQL Prompt. But it is configurable and FREE.

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) is pretty good.There's a full edition (About $100) and a free express edition!

Comment: I use SQL Complete on a daily basis and am very happy with it. My co-workers use Redgate's SQLPrompt, and considering the cost, DBForge is definitely the better option. In the past few months they've added such features as linked-server completion, and basic support for synonyms. I have personally reported bugs and feature requests to them and have /always/ received a prompt reply, and in the case of serious bugs, a prompt fix.